# Как конвертировать строку в словарь?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, словари

У меня есть функция которая обращается к Outline VPN серверу и возвращает кол-во байтов трафика использованного каждым ключом.

```
def get_traf(api_url):
    headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json"}
    url = api_url + "metrics/transfer"
    numofbytes = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    return numofbytes
```

Пример вывода у функции:

> {"bytesTransferredByUserId":{"0":8438180}}

Когда я попытался вывести в консоль этим методом:

```
traf = get_traf(api_url).text
print(traf.get("bytesTransferredByUserId")
```

Оказалось что это не словарь, а обычная строка и я получил эту ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Есть ли в Python способы конвертации строки в словарь?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сервис в данном случае возвращает json-строку. Для декодирования json в объект Python у результата запроса есть метод `json()`:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
numofbytes = response.json()
```

Это аналогично декодированию текста результата запроса с помощью `json.loads`:

```
import json

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
numofbytes = json.loads(response.text)
```

[В документации](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) также советуют перед вызовом `.json()` проверять код статус ответа (например, по условию `response.status == 200` или выбрасыванием исключения `response.raise_for_status()`), т.к. успешное выполнение метода `json()` не гарантирует, что пришел ответ с правильным статусом.

Comment: Я недавно узнал, что « response.raise_for_status()» работает таким образом, что в случае успешного статуса он ничего не делает. Поэтому вместо явной проверки статуса можно просто безусловно вызывать response.raise_for_status() , но это дело вкуса ;)

Answer (score 1):

И опасный ответ (так делать не рекомендуется, это просто теоретически):

```
real_dict = eval('{"bytesTransferredByUserId":{"0":8438180}}')
print(real_dict["bytesTransferredByUserId"])
```

> ```
> {"0": 8438180}
> ```